# Docker build failed

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, vora

I'm trying to install SAP Vora 2.0 on AWS Minikube but I'm getting this error: "Docker build failed." Have tried with version 2.1 of Vora but still encountering similar error.

This is the actual error log I'm getting:

```
Downloading/unpacking kubernetes
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1266, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.extras):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2401, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2597, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2621, in _compute_dependencies
    parsed = next(parse_requirements(distvers))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 49, in <lambda>
    next = lambda o: o.next()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2721, in parse_requirements
    "version spec")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2697, in scan_list
    raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", 'websocket-client !=0.40.0,!=0.41.*,!=0.42.*,>=0.32.0', 'at', '*,!=0.42.*,>=0.32.0')

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python python-pip python-twisted krb5-user vim &&     pip install kubernetes urllib3==1.19.1' returned a non-zero code: 2
Docker build failed !
```

Comment: Update docker file and add line `RUN pip install -U pip` after the `python-pip` installation command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below SAP note to resolve the issue:
https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2608651

Editing the post:

We need to edit 2 files to resolve this issue.

Locate the below file in Vora installation package & edit to add version:
{rootInstallDirectory}/images/vora-dqp/download_and_install_os_packages.sh

```
if [ -f /usr/bin/apt-get ]; then
...
pip install kubernetes==4.0.0 protobuf==3.5.1 httplib2==0.10.3 oauth2client==4.1.2 PySocks==1.6.8
...
elif [ -f /usr/bin/yum ]; then
pip install kubernetes==4.0.0 protobuf==3.5.1 httplib2==0.10.3 oauth2client==4.1.2 PySocks==1.6.8
...
```

Modify 2nd file: {rootInstallDirectory}/images/vora-security-operator/init-container/Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && \
...
pip install kubernetes==4.0.0 urllib3==1.19.1 PySocks==1.6.8
...
```

This issue will be fixed in next Vora patch.